# Symfony2 - How to customize the select option labels for the entity field type when using the query_builder?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

When i create an entity field in Symfony2, how i can specify the value of the select option-field generated ?

This is the snippet of my entity field:

```
->add('preferred_language', 'entity', array(
    'mapped' => false,
    'property' => 'name',
    'class' => 'Common\MainBundle\Entity\Language',
    'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC');
    }
```

Actually i can specify the shown value through the *property* and it takes automatically the id referred to the db table. Good. What can i do, instead, whether i want to change the option value?

```
<option value="my_value">my_property</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create an "entity" field, you create a relation form between two entities, so the default field value is the id annoted field on your entity.
You can change this behavior with a View Transformer. Check out this doc:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#model-and-view-transformers

Comment: Hi Paul, are you sure is it possible to do it by a data transformer?
Do you know any examples of how to change that entity behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

also looked for same solution and found it here: [different property for entity field type in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509459/additional-properties-to-entity-field-type-in-a-form-in-symfony2)

just set the property in the field type options and create a getter for the property that formats the string the way to output the label.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by the following way:

code in FormType must be the same:

```
->add('preferred_language', 'entity', array(
'mapped' => false,
'property' => 'name',
'class' => 'Common\MainBundle\Entity\Language',
'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC');
}
```

In the controller, I get the data with DQL:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyBundle:Language ORDER BY u.id DESC');
$data = $query->getResult();
```

I pass the data through render method:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:page.html.twig',
        array('formulario' => $formulario->createView(),
            'data' => $data));
```

In the twig file, I create a `<select>` item with id "myproject_mybundle_myformtype_**preferred_language**":

```
<select id="myproject_mybundle_myformtype_preferred_language" name="aeneagrama_adminbundle_itemcontenidotype[preferred_language]" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">-- Choose an option --</option>
    {% for item in data %}
        <option value="{{ item.your_column }}">{{ item.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}</select>
```

Finally, when you get input data from the form, you can get it in the controller:

```
$form->get('preferred_language')->getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller make this change,

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyBundle:Language u ORDER BY u.id DESC');
$data = $query->getResult();
```